# How to un-commit a file in git?

Tags: git, version-control

I have did `git commit <file>` for a file and also submitted that file with `git submit <file>`.
but now i want to un-commit the changes.
i have also tried `git reset HEAD~1 <file>` followed by `git checkout -- <file>`
but when i do `git update` it again comes as commited file.
can some one help me how can i un-commit my changes?

Comment: Simple.Commit the previous changes.

Comment: Did you try `git revert <commit>` ?

Comment: What is `git submit`?

Comment: `git update` is also unknown to me.

Comment: Do you want to forget about that commit and replace it with a fixed one, or make another commit that  deletes the file?

Comment: @cuonglm, @yaegashi, looks like `submit` is the alias for [`git hf feature submit`](https://github.com/datasift/gitflow/blob/master/git-hf-feature#L242). `update` is the alias for [`git hf update`](https://github.com/datasift/gitflow/blob/master/git-hf-update). See [HubFlowTools](http://datasift.github.io/gitflow/TheHubFlowTools.html). But I'm not sure:)

Comment: @cuonglm `git submit` is used to merge the changes to origin/master so that if some one does `git update` he will get all the new changes to his local repository.

Comment: If you've already published your commit to other people, I recommend you to do `git revert` and publish it again to avoid any troubles.  Take extreme care  when you attempt to rewrite the commit history.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the various scenarios listed in the book for rewriting history:

> https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

If you need more assistance, please write what you wish to achieve.